# ListItem height

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view for my Android app that should replace a huge Listview with custom cells. My cells used a RelativeLayout and `layout_height="match_parent"`

Now I wonder how the ListView knows how high each cell needs to be because it does obviously not fill the parent. So how does it determine how large the distance between the top and bottom elements of the RelativeLayout is.

Explaination:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wandering how does the `listview` know the `cell`'s sizes, it is thanks to her [onMeasure() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#onMeasure(int,%20int))

As you can read:

> Measure the view and its content to determine the measured width and
>   the measured height. This method is invoked by measure(int, int) and
>   should be overridden by subclasses to provide accurate and efficient
>   measurement of their contents.

In shorts, with this and other methods, the `ListView` can measure the `view`'s sizes and it will resize the view itself based on those measurements.

I hope this helped, if I misunderstood, please let me know

Comment: Yea I thought that it would use onMeasure() but how do you measure a RelativeLayout with things attatched to the bottom. So maybe the question should be how do i know how large the distance between the top and the bottom elements is.

Comment: @Ben you should be more specific on what you are trying to obtain, can you try to explain/draw it and implement the question?

Comment: Added a picture for explaination. Hope its clear now

Comment: @Ben the point is: what you need this space for and what you should display in it? Because if you just need an item in the topside and another item in the bottom side, you should just put one below the other and set height to wrap content. Is there a reason for using that alignment?

Comment: Might be an option but my app looks better if the items are far apart. So I've done it like this so the items can be far apart on big screens and have less distance between them on smaller screens

Comment: @Ben why not using margins?